# Composer installed in Synology DS916 NAS, unable to use ZIP command

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, synology

Installed composer in Synology DS916 and running Laravel 7.

when I use composer require Laravel/ui and composer require Laravel/passport to add package, composer have a message say not able to use ZIP command, download from source instead.

From phpinfo() and php -m, it looks zip package is enabled and running.

Does anybody can share some experience how to trace the problem ?

```
admin@ASCS:/volume1/web$ composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel new_project
Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./new_project"
Installing laravel/laravel (v8.0.3)
Failed to download laravel/laravel from dist: The zip extension and unzip command are both missing, skipping.
Your command-line PHP is using multiple ini files. Run `php --ini` to show them.
Now trying to download from source
- Installing laravel/laravel (v8.0.3): Cloning a6ca577839
---- omitted -----

admin@ASCS:/volume1/web$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php74/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php74/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php74/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php74/cli/conf.d/extension.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php74/cli/conf.d/timezone.ini
```

I try : which unzip => no result

Comment: Can you share the full and exact error message? Also, are you sure this is in any way related to Laravel itself?

Comment: Thanks Nico,  Question edited with error message.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? According to that error message, it looks pretty clear to me that the zip extension is **not** enabled

Comment: Thanks Nico,  is there some articles discuss how to trace zip extension in Synology NAS ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally installed unzip to the Synology NAS by first install Easy Bootstrap installer, then use ipkg command install the unzip package.

Answer (score 0):

I found out by reading on another forum that because zip had been removed from the official plugin set replaced by zlib, Synology had not included it with its distribution. They’ve since said they would include it in a coming update packade, but it has yet to happen. I’ve downgraded to 7.3 where zip is still avaialable, hoping that either Synology hold to their promise and include zip plugin or that framework developers start making their code using zlib alongside zip. Else the only way will be to get it will be to compile it from source or someone start distributing it in a community repo.